# Optional parameter in prepared query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

Using MySQL and PDO, I have the following prepared statement :

```
$stmt = $bdd->prepare('SELECT field FROM table WHERE category=:category;');
```

Then if I do the following, it works fine, I have all I want in `$results` :

```
$stmt->execute(array('category' => $someCategory));
$results = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

However, I **also** want to be able to execute the same statement, without the `WHERE` clause. Is it possible to execute the prepared statement and have it ignore the `WHERE` clause (for instance by passing no parameter in it) ?

Or do I have to make a new `SELECT field FROM table;` query ?

NB : `$stmt->execute();` returns `“No data supplied for parameters in prepared statement”` and `$stmt->execute(array('category' => ''));` returns nothing.

Thanks

Comment: Did you remove the `WHERE` clause from the query on your second attempt?

Comment: *"$stmt->execute(array('category' => '')); returns nothing."* --- exactly. You ask for nothing, you get just that; nothing. *Isn't that right Sam?* @JayBlanchard

Comment: `SELECT field, category` perhaps?

Comment: @JayBlanchard I modified the question to try to clarify it (I'm not english native), the question is precisely about not having to remove the `where` :)

Comment: clumsy but... You can add an `or` clause that tests the `placeholder` that is always true or never true as required. i.e. `category = :category  or :category = 'ignoreCategoryTest'`. The SQL optimiser will probably do something sensible with the test.

Comment: I'd use a ternary operator for this.

Comment: What is a ternary operator ?

Comment: you've also been given answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the `if...else` solution posed by @Oldskool is fine for this case, but here's another idea that might be helpful.

This allows you to have another parameters that toggles the filter (WHERE clause) on and off.

```
$stmt = $bdd->prepare('SELECT field FROM table WHERE (1=:filter AND category=:category) OR (0=:filter);');
$stmt->execute(array(
    'filter' => 1, //1 = on; 0 = off
    'category' => $someCategory));
$results = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't always have a category and want to run this query for both situations, a simple if/else construction would suffice:

```
if (!empty($someCategory)) {
    $stmt = $bdd->prepare('SELECT field FROM table WHERE category=:category;');
    $stmt->execute(array('category' => $someCategory));
} else {
    $stmt = $bdd->prepare('SELECT field FROM table;');
    $stmt->execute();
}

$results = $stmt->fetchAll();
```